# Database Engine Services Required to install ssrs?

Tags: virtual-machines, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have already installed sql server 2008 express and ssms on my vm... now I am trying to install ssrs on the same machine and keep getting "database engine error". Should I skip this [(click here please)](http://i49.tinypic.com/de1nys.jpg)

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall several times... even with administrator's mode, I get that error.

Comment: Are you trying to install SSRS 2008 or a different version like 2008 R2? Is 2008 Express installed as a default instance or with an instance name like "SQLEXPRESS"?

Comment: Hey Darin..yes, 2008 express is installed as a default instance as "SQLEXPRESS"... I am trying to create another instance "MSSQLSERVER" for SSRS from SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: The "default instance" is generally the one with no name. "default instance" doesn't mean "only one on the box". To make it more worse, sometimes MS refers to the unnamed instance as "MSSQLSERVER". I'm guessing that the SSRS instance that you are naming "MSSQLSERVER" is looking for a default instance of SQL (to store the SSRS metadata) I would try installing SSRS as SQLEXPRESS and see what happens. To be fair, I've never run SSRS on SQLEXPRESS, but some pages over at MSS seem to indicate that it works, with some caveats (like no scheduled reports because there is no SQL Agent).

Comment: that makes a lot of sense Darin... I am trying that now... will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Darin... I reinstalled in as SQLEXPRESS and didn't get any errors, however I had to manually configure SSRS after installation... thanks a bunch.... now how do I mark this question as 'answered'?

Comment: I presume that there is some icon that you can see and click, as the originator of the question, that I can't see. All I can find is this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work, which talks in generalities and does not seem to answer "How do I mark an answer as accepted?"

Comment: hmmm... looks like I can't mark this question as "answered' until you click "Post Your Answer" instead of adding comments... Post your solution that you gave me under "ANSWER", so that i can mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am summarizing the comments in this answer so that it can be accepted. Thx.)

The "default instance" is generally the one with no name. "default instance" doesn't mean "only one on the box". To make it more worse, sometimes MS refers to the unnamed instance as "MSSQLSERVER". I'm guessing that the SSRS instance that you are naming "MSSQLSERVER" is looking for a default instance of SQL (to store the SSRS metadata) I would try installing SSRS as SQLEXPRESS and see what happens.

To be fair, I've never run SSRS on SQLEXPRESS, but some pages over at MSS seem to indicate that it works, with some caveats (like no scheduled reports because there is no SQL Agent).

After installing SSRS, you may still need to manually configure SSRS.

Comment: Thanks Darin... this actually saved me a lot of headache